# execute mailx using shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to run the below script.

```
val = `wc -l /home/validate.bad | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n1`
valCount = `wc -l /home/validation.txt | awk '{print $1}'`
if [ "$val" -gt 1 ] && ["$valCount" -gt 1]
then
    mailx -s "Validation failed" -r xyz@abc.com xyz@abc.com<<-EOF
Hi ,
Validation has failed. Please check.
EOF
elif [ "$valCount" -gt 1 ]
then
    mailx -s "Validation pass" -r xyz@abc.com xyz@abc.com<<-EOF
Hi Team,
Validation success.
EOF
fi
```

But I am getting this error.

```
Error:
val: comand not found
valCount: command not found
line 3[: : integer expression expected
```

Comment: Assuming this is bash: You have spaces around the assignment operator. Use `val=` and `valCount=` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have spaces around `=` :

```
val = `wc -l /home/validate.bad | awk '{print $1}' | t` # wrong
```

and should have been

```
val=`wc -l /home/validate.bad | awk '{print $1}' | t`
```

or preferrably

```
val=$(wc -l </home/validate.bad) 
#`..` is legacy , $() supports nesting, one good reason to go for it
# You use awk and tail uselessly
```

Also

```
["$valCount" -gt 1]
```

should have been

```
[ "$valCount" -gt 1 ] # mind the spaces for the test constructie
# [spaceSTUFFspace] is the correct form
```

**Sidenote**

You may use [[ shellcheck ]](http://shellcheck.net) to check your scripts.